# How to using JPQL to join two tables

Tags: java, jpql

I made employee table and position table.Every Employees have one position.I want join two table ,but I don't know how to write code.

Employee.java

```
@Table(name = "employees")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getAllEmployees", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee AS e ORDER BY e.emp_id DESC")
})
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id", length = 8)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer emp_id;

    @Column(name = "emp_name", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String emp_name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "position", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", referencedColumnName = "emp_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "pos_id", referencedColumnName = "pos_id") })
    private Position pos;
    
    ～setter/getter～
```

Position.java

```
@Table(name = "position")

@Entity
public class Position {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pos_id")
    private Integer pos_id;

    @Column(name = "pos_name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String pos_name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pos")
    private Employee employee;
    
    ～setter/getter～
```

Comment: Just do like `... Employee AS e Join e.pos ...` And chose a different name for mapping table `position_employee` or you can do without the join table with a column in one side as foriegn key

Comment: Here is a details tutorial about JPA Join https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee.java
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id", length = 8)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer emp_id;

    @Column(name = "emp_name", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String emp_name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Position position;
```

```
Position.java
@Entity
public class Position {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int pos_id;

    @Column(name = "pos_name", length = 16)
    private String pos_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "position")
    private List<Employee> employees;
```

Thank you.I can join two tables!